# How can you increase/decrease the range(stretch/schrink) of Data?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convolution, data-analysis

Supposed,you have data could be a matrix or a flattened matrix.

°Standardadization & Normalization all deal with changing the scale.

°I want have a be a able to stretch the data such that my kernel and matrix fit together thereby bypassing padding.

For example if data was
A=[0110] range(A) = 3 to range (A) = 5 would be 'something like' , A=[0, 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0] perhaps not accurate but structure of data has been preserved and data points have been interpolated in order to fit the range.

°I am assuming stretching the z score and then converting it back but am not sure and do not know the procedure